# Misbehaving `Table`

Tags: string-manipulation, list-manipulation, output-formatting

(To be fair, it's not Mathematica that is 'misbehaving'; this is actually down to my limited coding skills.)

I have the following `Table`:

```
Module[{l = 5}, 
 table1 = Table[RandomInteger[{-100, 100}]/
      RandomInteger[{-100, 100}], {n, 1, l}]; 
 table2 = ContinuedFraction[table1]; 
  TableForm[Transpose[{table1, table2}], 
   TableHeadings -> {None, {"R", "CF of R"}}]]
```

The `ContinuedFraction` function produces the correct data, but not in `Table`-friendly form. The `"CF of R"` column lists the continued fractions vertically. I want some form of horizontal representation to make the `Table` more readable. In a totally ideal world, I'd like the continued fractions to appear as (for example)

```
[1;2,7,2,3,5]
```

i.e., reformatted so that (a) the continued fraction appears as a row in the `Table`, not a column-per-item, and (b) it uses standard traditional formatting.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you:

```
cfform[{b_, d___}] := Row[{"[", b, ";", ##, "]"}] & @@ Riffle[{d}, ","]

TableForm[{table1, cfform /@ table2}\[Transpose], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"R", "CF of R"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @Mr Wizard. Many thanks.